# Sorting data from text file

Tags: c++, sorting, visual-c++, text, parameter-passing

I need to write a program that reads an unknown number of numerical data from a text file into an array and then uses a sorting parameter to sort the numbers. I've been trying for hours and I can't get the program to work

```
void sort(double &, double arr[], int s);

int main()
{
    fstream myfile;
    int size, i = 0;
    const int n = 1000;
    double x[n];

    //reading data
    myfile.open("data.txt");
    if (myfile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
        myfile >> x[i];
        cout << x[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }
    size = i - 1;
    cout << size << " number of values in file" << endl;
    myfile.close();

    i = 0;
    while (size > i)
    {
        cout << x[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }
    //sorting
    sort(x[n], x[n], size);
    i = 0;
    while (size > i)
    {
        cout << x[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

void sort(double &, double arr[], int s)
{
    bool swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int tmp;
    while (swapped) 
    {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < s - j; i++) 
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
            {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                &[i + 1] = &tmp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'd recommend adding a tag to your answer for your programming language to attract answers from experts in that specific area.

Comment: @philtune I just did that for him. Also Stephan, what is the current problem with the code?

Comment: I'm going to suggest `&[i + 1] = &tmp` isn't going to do much of anything good. `std::swap` would be better than that trio of common code, and honestly `std::sort` would likewise be better than that bubble sort. And this: `while (!myfile.eof())` [**is wrong.**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: _@Stephan_Koellner_ Did you consider using [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: I have an error about converting from double to double and expecting a "{" in front of a lamdba body

Comment: Again, `&[i + 1] = &tmp;` makes no sense. That line should be `x[i+1] = tmp;` And `tmp` should be `double`, not `int`.

Comment: I need to have the sorting function as a parameter

Comment: Great. Describing what you *mean* by that in your question may save it from going on-hold. The first parameter to your sort function isn't even named.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (!myfile.eof())
```

is almost ALWAYS wrong, 
[Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/3093378)
as you end up reading the end of file. Use instead

```
while (myfile >> x[i])
```

In your case, you can just declare `x` as a `std::vector`, like

```
std::vector<double> x;
```

read the content into the vector, then use

```
std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());
```

Nothing more simple.

And for a complete C++ standard library solution, you can use iterators and sorting algorithms, like

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{ 
    std::fstream myfile("data.txt"); // should also test if it's open correctly
    std::vector<double> x(std::istream_iterator<double>(myfile), {});
    std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());

    for(const auto& elem: x)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
}
```

You can easily map the code above to a function. I have no idea what you mean by a sorting parameter. If you need to be able to sort ascending/descending, you may use `std::less` or `std::greater` (need to  `#include <functional>`), as a third parameter for `std::sort`, like

```
std::sort(x.begin(), x.end(), std::greater<double>()); // sorts in descending order
```

or write your own comparator functor/lambda function.

Comment: I changed my code to this

Comment: fstream myfile;
 int size, i = 0;
 const int n = 1000;
 std::vector<double> x;

 //reading data
 myfile.open("data.txt");
 if (myfile.fail()){
  cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
  exit(1);
 }
 while (!myfile.eof())
 {
  myfile >> x[i];
  cout << x[i] << endl;
  i++;
 }
 size = i - 1;
 cout << size << " number of values in file" << endl;
 myfile.close();

 i = 0;
 while (size > i)
 {
  cout << x[i] << endl;
  i++;
 }
 //sorting
 std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());
 i = 0;
 while (size > i)
 {
  cout << x[i] << endl;
  i++;
 }
 return 0;

Comment: You know you can initialize that vector with the istream iterators `std::vector<double> x((std::istream_iterator<double>(myfile)), std::istream_iterator<double>());` and skip the copy-step.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes I know, as they are iterators, but I felt it's just too much :) Although I guess it looks actually simpler, will update, thanks.

Comment: @StephanKoellner It's really hard to read your code in the comment. The `while(!myfile.eof())` is wrong, use what I pointed out above. Then test the code and see if it works! You also need to use the `push_back` function for `std::vector`. First, do `while(myfile >> tmp){ x.push_back(tmp); ....}`, where `tmp` is some temporary `double` declared before.

Answer (score 0):

My C++ is rusty and I am without a compiler, I will update this if any errors are encountered.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

static bool sort_function (double p, double q);

int main()
{
    fstream myfile;

    // opening file
    myfile.open("data.txt");
    if (myfile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // reading data and storing data
    vector<double> x;
    double tmp;
    while (myfile >> tmp)
    {
        x.push_back(tmp);
    }
    myfile.close();
    cout << x.size() << " number of values in file" << endl;

    // unsorted print data from vector
    for (vector<double>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }

    // sorted print data from vector
    sort(x.begin(), x.end(), sort_function);
    for (vector<double>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

static bool sort_function (double p, double q)
{
    return p > q;
}
```

There are some differences to your code.

- It uses `std::vector` instead of an array. It is dynamic and has some pleasant functionality like dynamic length, a size counter and sorting.
- I split it into four blocks of code, opening, storing, unsorted and sorting.

So what it does

1. As it were before, it tries to load `data.txt`, if it fails it exists.
2. It reads data, storing it in our temp variable `tmp` to then push it into our vector `x`. It then proceeds to close the file and print the number of values `x.size()`.
3. It prints the unsorted vector, as it were in your code.
4. It finally utilizes `std::sort(begin, end, function)` to sort the vector.